# Scrapy beginner gets exception

Tags: scrapy

i need help. I wanted to do a crawler for a specific website (underminejournal). I want to get this data from the site to create a console output for me, because i mostly work on consoles and dont want to switch that often. The other point is i want to push the data in a database (sql etc is no problem). But somehow i just get this displayed when i try to execute the crawler, the tutorial is not really helpful i think:

```
2016-10-05 10:55:23 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: undermine)
2016-10-05 10:55:23 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2016-10-05 10:55:23 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'undermine.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['undermine.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'undermine'}
2016-10-05 10:55:23 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-10-05 10:55:23 [boto] DEBUG: Retrieving credentials from metadata server.
2016-10-05 10:55:24 [boto] ERROR: Caught exception reading instance data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/utils.py", line 210, in retry_url
    r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1228, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2016-10-05 10:55:24 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up
2016-10-05 10:55:24 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-10-05 10:55:24 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-10-05 10:55:24 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2016-10-05 10:55:24 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-10-05 10:55:24 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-10-05 10:55:24 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-10-05 10:55:24 [scrapy] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 110, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 70, in start_requests
    yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 73, in make_requests_from_url
    return Request(url, dont_filter=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 24, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 59, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: theunderminejournal.com/#eu/eredar/item/124442
2016-10-05 10:55:24 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-10-05 10:55:24 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 5, 8, 55, 24, 710944),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/ERROR': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 5, 8, 55, 24, 704378)}
2016-10-05 10:55:24 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

My spider is this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class JournalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "journal"
    allowed_domains = ["theunderminejournal.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'theunderminejournal.com/#eu/eredar/item/124442',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        page = respinse.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'journal-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
            self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
        pass
```

Someone know a hint?

**EDIT RESULTS**

```
2016-10-05 11:21:35 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: undermine)
2016-10-05 11:21:35 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2016-10-05 11:21:35 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'undermine.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['undermine.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'undermine'}
2016-10-05 11:21:35 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-10-05 11:21:35 [boto] DEBUG: Retrieving credentials from metadata server.
2016-10-05 11:21:36 [boto] ERROR: Caught exception reading instance data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/utils.py", line 210, in retry_url
    r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1228, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2016-10-05 11:21:36 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up
```

Answer (score 0):

`ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: theunderminejournal.com/#eu/eredar/item/124442`

Your urls should always start with either `http://` or `https://`.

```
start_urls = (
    'theunderminejournal.com/#eu/eredar/item/124442',
    # ^ should be:
    'http://theunderminejournal.com/#eu/eredar/item/124442',
)
```

Comment: The error in your edit is completely unrelated and cause by `boto` package, which cannot connect to somewhere. You can most likely ignore it. Does the spider itself work?